# Images are overlapping the header in AMP (CSS problem)

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I want to ask you for help with adapting AMP version of website: https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/roman-society/amp/

I am able to make fixed HEADER bar by adding css code

```
nav.amphtml-title {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but once I am scrolling down I can see images are overlapping the header. Below screen:
[image]

I see that guilty is ***position: absolute;*** in below code

```
.i-amphtml-layout-size-defined .i-amphtml-fill-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

But do not know what to change to appear the image + have it under the header bar.
Do you know what change I need to do in CSS for elements to be able to correct it?

Below if part of code from AMP version where is located headr

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="amphtml-title" style="position: fixed;width: 100%;">
        <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/amp/">
                                            <amp-img src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo-2.png" width="32" height="32" alt="logo" class="amphtml-site-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; --loader-delay-offset: 47ms !important;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed"><img decoding="async" alt="logo" src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo-2.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
                                                                IMPERIUM ROMANUM                    </a>
    </div>
                                <div class="sidebar-header">
            <section class="icon-button-section">
                            <button id="menu-search" class="amp-menu-sidebar hamburger icon-button" on="tap:search-lightbox"><amp-img src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-search.png" width="68" height="68" alt="Search" class="amphtml-site-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" style="width: 68px; height: 68px; --loader-delay-offset: 47ms !important;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed"><img decoding="async" alt="Search" src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-search.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
                                                        </button>
                        <button class="amp-menu-sidebar hamburger icon-button" on="tap:amp-sidebar.toggle">                     <amp-img src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-menu.png" width="68" height="68" alt="Menu" class="amphtml-site-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" style="width: 68px; height: 68px; --loader-delay-offset: 47ms !important;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed"><img decoding="async" alt="Menu" src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-menu.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
                                                        </button>
                </section>
            </div>
            </div>
<div>
  <amp-lightbox id="search-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-nodisplay i-amphtml-overlay i-amphtml-built" i-amphtml-layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
<div class="lightbox-menu" tabindex="0">
<button class="lightbox-close" on="tap:search-lightbox.close">
<amp-img src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-close.png" width="68" height="68" alt="Close" class="amphtml-site-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built" style="width: 68px; height: 68px;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed"></amp-img>
                        </button>
                            </div>              
    <div class="lightbox-search" tabindex="0">
       <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form i-amphtml-form" action="https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/amp/" target="_top" novalidate="">
    <label>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s">
        <input type="hidden" name="is_amp" value="1">
            </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
</form>    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
                            
<amp-lightbox id="n-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-nodisplay i-amphtml-overlay i-amphtml-built" i-amphtml-layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
<div class="lightbox-menu" tabindex="0">
<button class="lightbox-close" on="tap:n-lightbox.close">
<amp-img src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/icons/amp-close.png" width="68" height="68" alt="Close" class="amphtml-site-icon i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built" style="width: 68px; height: 68px;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed"></amp-img>
                        </button>
                            </div>              
    <div class="lightbox-search" tabindex="0">
       <div class="newsletter-wrapper">
  <form id="pop_newsletter" name="submit" method="post" action-xhr="//imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/themes/romanum/wp-amp/includes/mailchimp-pop.php" target="_top" novalidate="" class="i-amphtml-form amp-form-dirty">
    <h2>Subscribe to the newsletter!</h2>
    <p>Do you want to be up to date with news, curiosities and discoveries from the world of ancient Romans? Subscribe to the newsletter! The newsletter will be sent every Saturday.</p>
    <input type="email" name="pop_email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required="">
   <label for="pop_lang"><span>Language</span>
    <select name="pop_lang" required="">
       <option value="2">English</option>
    <option value="1">Polish</option>
      </select></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
    <div submit-success="">
       <template type="amp-mustache">
         Thank you! Check {{email_address}} to confirm your subscription.       </template>
   </div>
      <div submit-error="">
       <template type="amp-mustache">
         Ooops... Something went wrong. Please try again later.    </template>
   </div>
  </form>
</div>    </div>
</amp-lightbox> </div></nav>
    <div id="main">
    <div class="target">
    <a class="target-anchor" id="top"></a>
    <amp-position-observer on="enter:hideAnim.start; exit:showAnim.start" layout="nodisplay" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-nodisplay i-amphtml-built" i-amphtml-layout="nodisplay" hidden=""></amp-position-observer>
    </div>
<amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-nodisplay i-amphtml-built" i-amphtml-layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "duration": "200ms",
      "fill": "both",
      "iterations": "1",
      "direction": "alternate",
      "animations": [{
        "selector": "#scrollToTopButton",
        "keyframes": [{
          "opacity": "0.9",
          "visibility": "visible"
        }]
      }]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
<amp-animation id="hideAnim" layout="nodisplay" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-nodisplay i-amphtml-built" i-amphtml-layout="nodisplay" hidden="">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "duration": "200ms",
      "fill": "both",
      "iterations": "1",
      "direction": "alternate",
      "animations": [{
        "selector": "#scrollToTopButton",
        "keyframes": [{
          "opacity": "0",
          "visibility": "hidden"
        }]
      }]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>      
        <div class="inner">
<div class="amp-ad"><amp-ad width="0" height="320" type="adsense" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1752121314293437" data-ad-slot="5827352308" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built" style="width: 100%; height: 320px;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" data-amp-slot-index="0" data-a4a-upgrade-type="amp-ad-network-adsense-impl">
  <div overflow=""></div>
<div fallback=""><div class="i-amphtml-ad-default-holder" data-ad-holder-text="Ad"></div></div><amp-analytics sandbox="true" trigger="immediate" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" aria-hidden="true" hidden=""><script type="application/json">{"requests":{"csi":"https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?"},"transport":{"xhrpost":false},"triggers":{"adRequestStart":{"on":"ad-request-start","request":"csi","sampleSpec":{"sampleOn":"a4a-csi-${pageViewId}","threshold":1},"selector":"amp-ad","selectionMethod":"closest","extraUrlParams":{"met.a4a":"afs_lvt.${viewerLastVisibleTime}~afs.${time}"}},"adResponseEnd":{"on":"ad-response-end","request":"csi","sampleSpec":{"sampleOn":"a4a-csi-${pageViewId}","threshold":1},"selector":"amp-ad","selectionMethod":"closest","extraUrlParams":{"met.a4a":"afe.${time}"}},"adRenderStart":{"on":"ad-render-start","request":"csi","sampleSpec":{"sampleOn":"a4a-csi-${pageViewId}","threshold":1},"selector":"amp-ad","selectionMethod":"closest","extraUrlParams":{"met.a4a":"ast.${scheduleTime}~ars_lvt.${viewerLastVisibleTime}~ars.${time}","qqid":"${qqid}"}},"adIframeLoaded":{"on":"ad-iframe-loaded","request":"csi","sampleSpec":{"sampleOn":"a4a-csi-${pageViewId}","threshold":1},"selector":"amp-ad","selectionMethod":"closest","extraUrlParams":{"met.a4a":"ail.${time}"}}},"extraUrlParams":{"s":"ampad","ctx":"2","c":"${correlator}","slotId":"${slotId}","puid":"${requestCount}~${timestamp}"}}</script></amp-analytics></amp-ad></div>
        
<div class="amphtml-content  amphtml-single-page single-content">
                                    <div class="okruszki">
    <!-- Breadcrumb NavXT 7.2.0 -->
<span><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to IMPERIUM ROMANUM." href="https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/" class="home">Home</a></span>  » <span><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Idź do Roman society." href="https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/roman-society/" class="post post-page current-item">Roman society</a></span></div>                                                                                      <div class="titlediv">
    <h1 class="amphtml-title">Roman society</h1>
<p class="lang_sel">This post is also available in: <strong><a href="https://imperiumromanum.pl/spoleczenstwo/">Polish</a></strong> (<a href="https://imperiumromanum.pl/spoleczenstwo/">polski</a>)</p></div>                                      <amp-img lightbox="" src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Pompeii-couple-e1664121350864-600x582.jpg" layout="responsive" width="600" height="582" alt="Fresco showing a Roman couple" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" on="tap:amp-lightbox-gallery.activate" style="--loader-delay-offset: 47ms !important;"><i-amphtml-sizer slot="i-amphtml-svc" style="padding-top: 97%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
    <img decoding="async" alt="Fresco showing a Roman couple" src="https://imperiumromanum.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Pompeii-couple-e1664121350864-600x582.jpg" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
    
        <div class="chmurka_feat"><p class="opis_feat">Fresco showing a Roman couple</p></div>
```

Thank you.
Regards,
Jakub

Comment: How can we help if we can't see the source of the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what exactly you would need for checking the issue?

Comment: your source code. SO prefers it to be inline - not an external file. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for more questions - but you need i.e. page source (right click in page > View Page source), some part of code etc?

I thought it will be easier for others just to go to affected page with mobile view of page and right click to investigated object?

Please help me understand what will be helpful then.

Comment: The page is not an AMP page. How can we offer advice if it's not on the target question?

Comment: Thank you. I have such plugin on Firefox that enables mobile appearance of page. If this is not good pls just tell me how to provide source code that will be enough for you.

Comment: See MCVE above. Many SO advisors will downvote a question that fails MCVE.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware about rules here. I added the bigger part of code from AMP version of page. There are present both: header and image code.
Can you please check if this is enough and maybe you have an idea what is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: If you want SO assistance you need to read and then apply the instructions from MCVE above.